# Azure vue issuse with missing server.js/app.js?

Tags: azure, vue.js, azure-web-app-service

I am new to web development and I have tried to upload my vue app to a azure web app service but i am getting some problems

so when I try to try to open the webpage up it says

> "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

I have been trying to follow a few guide about a web.config file, and when i added it, the message disappered, but now it shows nothing. Then i tried to take a look at my output when i try to upload my code, here it says

> missing server.js/app.js

my app file is a vue file, but i don´t really know how to fix this, it´s also not located at the root but in a src folder

---

i added the web config file to the public folder

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    
    <!-- indicates that the index.js file is a node.js application 
    to be handled by the iisnode module -->
    
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    
    <!-- adds index.js to the default document list to allow 
    URLs that only specify the application root location, 
    e.g. http://mysite.antarescloud.com/ -->
    
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <add value="index.js" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you using Visual studio code or Visual Studio ?

Comment: i use visual studio code

Comment: Please share the settings which you have added in web.config

Comment: i have edited the post with the web config file

Comment: Do you have index.js in your folder structure?

Comment: https://github.com/Vampiredk/samplevue/tree/master/src/router just posting my github so it´s maybe easier, but i got a index.js file located in a folder called router

Comment: The web.config which you have provided in comment is not same as the one which is in git hub.Please check and confirm the same in KUDU console.